# checking Email availablity using AJAX in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

i need to check email availablity for this task. while i enter any email address, after i press tab it should check in the database and return whether this email are already exist or not.
but this routine gives exact output as what i expect while checking it in console. but the error message didn't written on my html page. can any one help me? thanks in advance.

**HTML coding**

```
<div class="txtinputcomp">
   <input name="frmVisitorEmail" id="frmVisitorEmail" onblur="checkEmail(this.value);" class="emailbox" required="required" value="<?php echo $_POST['frmVisitorEmail']; ?>" placeholder="Visitor Email" type="email" />   
    </div>
<div class="emptytxtcomp">
     <span id="errorEmail" class="errorStyle"></span>
 </div>
```

**FindEmail.php**

```
<?php
    include("includes/config.php"); 
    $strEmail = $_GET["email"];
    $strData = doCheckEmail($strEmail);
    if($strData!=0) {
        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
            document.getElementById('errorEmail').innerHTML = 'Email address are already exist!';
            return false;
        </script>";

    } else {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> 
            document.getElementById("errorEmail").innerHTML = "";
        </script>';
    }
?>
```

**AJAX script**

```
function checkEmail(str)
{
    var xmlhttp;
    if (str.length==0) {
        document.getElementById("frmVisitorEmail").innerHTML="";
        return;
    }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            document.getElementById("frmVisitorEmail").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","findEmail.php?email="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

**Function**

```
function doCheckEmail($strIdent)
    {
        $strSelectsSql = "Select count(*) as TotalCnt from tbl_visitor Where visitor_email='".$strIdent."' ";
        $strSelectsResult = SelectQry($strSelectsSql);
        return $strSelectsResult[0][0];
    }


function SelectQry($Qry) {
        $result = mysql_query($Qry) or die ("QUERY Error:".$Qry."<br>".mysql_error());      
        $numrows = mysql_num_rows($result); 
        if ($numrows == 0) {            
            return;
        } else {
           $row = array(); 
           $record = array();
           while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
                $record[] = $row; 
           }        
        }   
        return MakeStripSlashes($record);
    }
```

Comment: Javascript doesn't get run when you insert a script with `innerHTML`.

Comment: Whoa there ! (Off topic but) this code is an SQL Injection attack waiting to happen!

Comment: Instead of returning a script, why don't you just return the `errorEmail` content, and have the callback function insert it there.

Comment: I didn't get u brother.. @Barmar

Comment: BTW easier and less code if you use jQuery [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: No brother, i should not use this script by using jQuery. i need to go on with javaScript. @mTorres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line won't run the script that the PHP is echoing:

```
document.getElementById("frmVisitorEmail").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
```

In order to execute dynamically-added Javascript, you have to use `createElement` to create a `script` element.

Instead, I suggest that the PHP just return the error message, not a script block. So it should be:

```
if($strData!=0) {
    echo "Email address are already exist!";
} else {
    echo "";
}
```

Then the Javascript would be:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        document.getElementById("errorEmail").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless he goes down the dark road of `eval()`, your answer is a suitable one.

Also, it would be much preferred if PHP echoes HTTP headers corresponding to the result, aka 200 response if email not found, and 400 response if email is found.